# Why does java.util.concurrent.RunnableFuture have a run() method?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, concurrent.futures

As I was going through JDK 7, I found that `java.util.concurrent.RunnableFuture<V>` has a run method. I wonder what the significance of duplicating the same run method signature in the interface is when it already extends `Runnable`.

```
package java.util.concurrent;

public interface RunnableFuture<V> extends Runnable, Future<V> {
    /**
     * Sets this Future to the result of its computation
     * unless it has been cancelled.
     */
    void run();
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's defined in the interface so that they can attach `RunnableFuture`-specific JavaDoc to it. There's no *technical* significance.

Comment: Thanks! This is more meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are no docs that provide such explanation. So I am going to provide my opinion.

I dont think it has any major significance. Imagine how the interface world look

```
public interface RunnableFuture<V> extends Runnable, Future<V> {
}
```

Though it is perfectly valid it does not clearly indicate its purpose. So in my opinion it is just been provided for easy understanding for `run()` method specific to `RunnableFuture` interface. So that you know to put your runnable logic by overriding `run()` method.

Another point that I can think of is `Runnable` is one of the early interfaces and if you see the run() method it is

```
public abstract void run();
```

and  `public` and `abstract` keywords are redundant as methods in an interface are by default  `public` and `abstract`. To improvise this might be one of the reasons.

Comment: Well, if we considering looks and redundancy then I agree with you... ;)

Comment: My answer also incorporate the answer that has been accepted. `provided for easy understanding for run() method specific to RunnableFuture interface`. Anyway good to know you agree ;)